# Is the new version of this code more difficult to read and understand than the original? How can it be improved?

Tags: c#

I was asked to do a code review for the following block of code. It implemented a bug fix to prevent some values being added to some drop down lists depending on the user's domain, in an ASP.NET WebForms app. The three lines adding items to the lists were from the pre-bug-fix code (not part of the fix), so I didn't review it.

```
        //Only add corporate AD domain if the user is a member of it.
        string domainName = "";
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal == null) 
        {
            //"Missing the thread identity";
        }
        else if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") < 0)
        {
            //"No domain detected leave domain name blank.";
        }
        else
        {
            domainName = Utils.GetUserDomain(Thread.CurrentPrincipal).ToUpper();
        }

        if (domainName == Config.AppSettings.Domain.ToUpper())
        {
              domainUserDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain, Config.AppSettings.Domain));
              domainOfficeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain, Config.AppSettings.Domain));
              domainTypeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain, Config.AppSettings.Domain));
        }
```

I reviewed the code and suggested changing the code to the following:

```
        //Only add corporate AD domain if the user is a member of it.
        var currentPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        var hasDomain = currentPrincipal != null && currentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Contains("\\");
        var domainName = hasDomain ? Utils.GetUserDomain(currentPrincipal) : null;

        if (string.Equals(domainName, Config.AppSettings.Domain, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
              domainUserDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain, Config.AppSettings.Domain));
              domainOfficeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain, Config.AppSettings.Domain));
              domainTypeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain, Config.AppSettings.Domain));
        }
```

When the original developer saw the changes, he agreed with some of it (change of IndexOf to Contains, and ToUpper to String.Equals for case insensitive search), but not all of it. His main complaint was that the new code was more difficult to read and understand, and that the if blocks were clearer than the ternary operator. We weren't able to come to a point of agreement.

Could you please review both the original and new code and suggest improvements to either. Also, please point out any problems in the new code, especially where you think it is worse than the original code.

Comment: What does `Utils.GetUserDomain()` do when it's passed `null` or principal without a domain? Wouldn't it make sense to change that?

Comment: @svick - I'm not sure what it does exactly. It was existing code and outside of scope for the code I was reviewing. Both sets of code prevent a principal without a domain being passed into `GetUserDomain`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//These two lines of code tells you exactly what's happening without burying
//you with the details. It almost reads like plain English instead of code.
if(IsMemberOfCorporateDomain(Thread.CurrentPrincipal))
    AddCorporateDomainToDropDowns();


private void AddCorporateDomainToDropDowns()
{    
   //I don't think you need to set both Text and Value, 
   //check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx

   domainUserDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain));
   domainOfficeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain));
   domainTypeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain));
}

private bool IsMemberOfCorporateDomain(IPrincipal principal)
{
    var domainName = GetDomainName(principal);

    return domainName != null && domainName.Equals(Config.AppSettings.Domain, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

//This function's only job is to get domain name from a given principal.
//This will allow you to use this function elsewhere if needed. 
private string GetDomainName(IPrincipal principal)
{
    if(principal == null || principal.Identity == null || principal.Identity.Name == null)
        return null;

    if(principal.Identity.Name.Contains("\\"))
        return null;

    return Utils.GetUserDomain(principal.Identity.Name);
}
```

That's how I would do it. As I wrote in my comment elsewhere, the advantages are:

1. The code becomes self documenting. Now you know the 'semantics' of the code without having to read the actual code.
2. If for some reason there is a bug in a function (say GetDoaminName) and it throws an Exception, the last function in stack trace will be 'GetDomainName'. It immediately makes it clear where the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review and thanks for your answer! In general, feel free to explain your choices a bit more.

Comment: @QuentinPradet For some reason, I am not able to format the code anymore. Could you please help?

Comment: It's great as it is, isn't it?

Comment: @QuentinPradet Well, I figured out how to fix it. But thanks for checking! :)

Comment: @SolutionYogi, why would you return null from GetDomainName?  What's wrong with string.Empty?

Comment: `private void AddCorporateDomainToDropDowns()` is too repetitive for my taste. I do not know what the remedy would be, but I do not like that repetition - it does not scale.

Comment: @SolutionYogi - `IsMemberOfCorporateDomain` is at risk of a `NullReferenceException` if `GetDomainName` returns null. `String.Equals` would fix that.

Comment: @SolutionYogi - I like how your solution has changed the main code to `if(IsMemberOfCorporateDomain(Thread.CurrentPrincipal))
    AddCorporateDomainToDropDowns();`. That is awesome, very compact and readable. However, overall, your code listing is now much larger than either of the original code pieces. That bit makes me a little uneasy. I do like the code more readable, but I also prefer less code too.

Comment: @GiddyUpHorsey Sorry, I missed that NRE. I fixed that problem. BTW, I don't think the code listing is much larger. Mainly, I am doing additional check that principal.Identity and principal.Identity.Name is not null either because I don't see any guarantees in docs that they won't be null. Personally, if I had two choices, few more lines of code v/s readability, I will pick the later. Remember, you read code way more often than you write it. Additionally, I also care about how my stack trace looks like when an Exception occurs.

Comment: @JeffVanzella Personally, I like to use Code Contracts to mark methods as Null or Not Null returning so that static analysis can check for errors during compile time itself. Returning string.Empty won't help the static analyzer.

Comment: @Leonid Could you clarify what you mean by `IsMemberOfCorporateDomain` being repetitive?

Comment: @SolutionYogi, not what I wrote. I find `someDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Config.AppSettings.Domain));` x 3 repetitive.

Comment: @Leonid Oh, I see. But there are three drop downs. There is no way to avoid writing three lines of code to populate three drop downs.

Answer (score 16):

Disclaimer: I'm not too familiar with C#.

The modified form has expressions that are a little too complex for me, but either would be ok. My only comment is that the initial comment line is screaming for some notice:

```
// Only add corporate AD domain if the user is a member of it.
```

Why not take all the tests and put them into a function?

```
if ( IsMemberOfCorporateDomain( Thread.CurrentPrincipal ) ) ...
```

Then, depending on how you both feel about early exits:

```
private bool IsMemberOfCorporateDomain( IPrincipal currentPrincipal )
{
    if ( currentPrincipal == null ) return false;
    if ( !currentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Contains("\\") ) return false;

    var domainName = Utils.GetUserDomain(currentPrincipal);
    return string.Equals( domainName, Config.AppsSettings.Domain, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
}
```

Comment: +100. This is what self documenting code is. The advantages of this approach: 1. Now you know the 'semantics' of the code without having to read the actual code. 2. If for some reason there is a bug in the function and it throws an Exception, the last function in stack trace will be 'IsMemberOfCorporateDomain'. It immediately makes it clear about what went wrong. 3. Helps tremendously when reading the code. Let's me get to the meat of the program i.e. updating the drop down lists.

Comment: Here's how I would do it: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/26435/4405

Comment: Good point. This is essentially the _Extract Method_ refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

Both solutions have their merits. The original code is very easy to read, well commented and employs good use of vertical space. Beyond the points you already mentioned, I find that the conditional feels backwards. It may have been easier to read as

```
if (we have a domain name) {
  domainName = ...;
} else {
  // nope
}
```

i.e. we test for the positive case, not for negations. Hiding the important part in an `else` is dubious.

Your code does this, but presents two rather cluttered lines. It is slightly more self-documenting, but lacks visual structure. We can add parens to make the `?:` stand out more:

```
(hasDomain) ? (Utils.GetUserDomain(currentPrincipal)) : (null)
```

Or, preferably, use an if-statement again:

```
var domainName = "";
if ( currentPrincipal != null
  && currentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Contains("\\")  // must detect a domain
) {
    domainName = Utils.GetUserDomain(currentPrincipal);
}
```

This splits the condition across multiple lines, thus making them easy to grok. Specifically, the formatting emphasizes operator precedence. On the right of each part of the condition, space for comments remains. I prefer `""` over `null` (self-documenting), but you may have style guides that mandate one solution.

How the closing paren of the condition is formatted is an open question. I've shown the solution I use, but indenting the `) {` by two spaces may be preferable, or even splitting them across two lines:

```
if (  condA
   && condB
   )
{
  ...;
}
```

You may have style guides which mandate a certain style.

The `currentPrinciple` variable is a valuable addition, as it simplifies the remaining code.

The not-reviewed code is sightly painful:

1. it should use a loop to perform the same action on multiple objects.
2. it should have been vertically aligned when no loop is used.
3. `domainXDropDownList` is reverse Hungarian Notation. The prefix `domain` indicates you may want to use an object with properties `User`, `Office` and `Type`. The suffix `DropDownList` is type information that should rather be expressed by the type system, so maybe another class.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I am reviewing your changes only, as per FAQ. "How to do a codereview" might be a question more suitable for [programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Glenn has already pointed out that the newly added code should be extracted to another method(+1). I suggest a different signature. Before the method had no knowledge of thread or user principles, therefore it need not now either. And pulling the domain name from configuration in two different places is not a good idea.

```
        string corporateDomain = Config.AppSettings.Domain;

        if (canAddDomain(corporateDomain))
        {
              domainUserDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(corporateDomain, corporateDomain));
              domainOfficeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(corporateDomain, corporateDomain));
              domainTypeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(corporateDomain, corporateDomain));
        }

        private canAddDomain(string domain) {
            IsMemberOfDomain(Thread.CurrentPrincipal, domain)
        }
// where IsMemberOfDomain is as Glenn implemented except domain is extracted as a parameter
```

As a next step refactoring these should probably be extracted as fields: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`, `Config.AppSettings.Domain`

That many dots and dependence on static properties makes your code untestable. Any bugs cannot be detected until it is pushed to production and when a bug occurs it would not be clear whether it is a configuration error or a programming error.

Comment: I totally agree with caching the `corporateDomain` value, but as stated in the question, that part of the code wasn't under review. It is part of the existing mess :) Thank you for the suggestion though. If I were writing the original code I would have done it your way too.

Answer (score 2):

I normally format my ternary expressions (for the purposes of readability) as follows:

```
var hasDomain = currentPrincipal != null &&
    currentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Contains("\\");

var domainName = hasDomain ? 
    Utils.GetUserDomain(currentPrincipal) : 
    null;
```

Perhaps this is an acceptable compromise?

Answer (score 0):

- I would extract a static method named `GetDomainNameIfPresent()` (`GetDomainNameOrNull()` might also be a good name for that).
- I would extract another method: `AddDomainFromAppSettingsToDropDownLists()`

By extracting these methods, you get a more self-documenting code (that nedds less comments) and that is more likely to be re-used instead of re-written.

But looking at the bigger picture, you might want to take advantage of MVVM and data binding (WPF). Then you would not operate on the `Items` property of the `ComboBox`es, but on the collection(s) that are bound to their `ItemsSource` property.